# How to pass multiple variables from a string into a query

Tags: sql, oracle

How do you pass multiple variables in the form of a string?

I had this issue, when trying to make a query (And I couldn't use a procedure)

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  xxxx
WHERE 
  id IN ( 913456,412548,1225 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
in_ids := '1;457;988;';

SELECT Substr(in_ids, a.pos_from, a.length) ids
FROM   (SELECT Lag(c.poscomma, 1, 0) over (ORDER BY c.poscomma)
               + 1                   pos_from,
               c.poscomma            pos_to,
               Abs(Lag(c.poscomma, 1, 0) over (ORDER BY c.poscomma)
                   + 1 - c.poscomma) length
        FROM   (SELECT Substr(in_ids, LEVEL, 1) AS CHARACTER,
                       LEVEL                  AS poscomma
                FROM   dual
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Length(in_ids)) c
        WHERE  c.CHARACTER = ';') a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK');
```

[Checkout this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Comment: It was actually a Q&A answer, so I already had it. I needed to pass a parameter into a query, because I was using a tool that is unable to work with procedures and refcursors.